# How can I change the default connection string settings for VS server explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2008, connection-string, server-explorer

I use SQL Server 2005 express and desing the DB in server explorer in VS2008. Due to various reasons I have disabled user instances. Now every time I use server explorer I need to modify the connection and turn user instances off.

Is there a way to configure VS to always connect with user instance = false?